# Can't import existing project in eclipse

Tags: java, android

Failed to read the project description file (`.project`) for 'MainActivity'. The file has been changed on disk, and it now contains invalid information. The project will not function properly until the description file is restored to a valid state

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a backup of the files
2. Delete all configuration files.
3. Import the project again using File -> Import... -> Existing Project into Workspace.